# React useState not seems to be working with eventlisteners (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, state, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a webpage which have a fixed hamburger icon on the top right and when clicked opens a navbar. If user clicks outside of navbar, the navbar should be closed and hamburger icon should came again.

I use nextjs and nextjs don't accept user interactions in server side components therefore i had to open another file called CrMenuWrapper.

```js
'use client'
import logger from '@/utils/logger'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

interface Props { }

const CrMenuWrapper: NextPage<Props> = ({ }) => {

    const [isMenuClicked, setIsMenuClicked] = useState(false)
    const phoneMenu: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null)
    const menuButton: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null)

    logger(isMenuClicked)


    function handleOnClick(e: any) {
        
        if (phoneMenu.current && isMenuClicked && !phoneMenu.current.contains(e.target)) {
            setIsMenuClicked(prevIsMenuClicked => !prevIsMenuClicked)
        } else if (menuButton.current && !isMenuClicked && menuButton.current.contains(e.target)) {
            logger("clicked")
            setIsMenuClicked(prevIsMenuClicked => !prevIsMenuClicked)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', (e) => handleOnClick(e))
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', (e) => handleOnClick(e))
        };
    }, [])

    return <div>
        <div ref={phoneMenu} className={`fixed z-50 bg-gradient-to-bl from-violet-600/30 backdrop-blur-sm to-indigo-600/30  bg-no-repeat bg-top top-0 right-0 transition-all border-2 border-[var(--secondary-rgb)] 
        w-[75vw] aspect-square rounded-es-full md:hidden origin-top-right duration-300 
        ${isMenuClicked ? " scale-100 rotate-0" : " scale-0 rotate-45"}`}>

        </div>
        <div ref={menuButton} className={` bg-transparent md:hidden fixed aspect-square h-12 top-10 backdrop-blur-md right-10 stroke-0 hover:cursor-pointer
        border-[var(--secondary-rgb)] p-2.5 rounded-full border-2 hover:scale-125 transition-all  opacity-70 hover:opacity-100
        ${isMenuClicked ? " scale-0" : " scale-100"}`}>
            <svg id="nav-svg" stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" className={`fill-[var(--primary-rgb)] 
            `} viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="inherit" width="inherit" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="nav-path" d="M16 18V20H5V18H16ZM21 11V13H3V11H21ZM19 4V6H8V4H19Z"></path></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default CrMenuWrapper
```

*CrMenuWrapper.tsx*

The problem is when clicked to button, it scales button to 0 and opens nav-bar; however when i try to click outside of the nav, it doesn't close. Furthermore, when i log the isMenuClicked inside of handleOnClick, it logs false; however when i put it upon it (as in above), it logs true and then doesn't update itself.

Can i 10x coder help me w/this?

[image: default view]

[image: Nav-Bar view]

Thx,

Comment: let me know if you need any other files :)

Comment: I'd recommend using https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-on-click-outside or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-focus-on to capture click events outside of your menu element. Furthermore, your `handleOnClick` function will either need to be moved within the useEffect or wrapped in useMemo, since it is a dependency of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It seems bcs of the event listeners, the state updated inside of handleOnClick won't affect the rest of the page. Therefore i uses `closest`function in order to do it and it works rn.

The function body seems like that:

```js
const [isMenuClicked, setIsMenuClicked] = useState(false)
    const phoneMenu: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null)
    const menuButton: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null)


    function handleOnClick(e: any) {


        if (e.target.closest(".menuButton")) {
            setIsMenuClicked(true)
        }

        else if (phoneMenu.current?.classList.contains("scale-100") && null == e.target.closest(".phoneMenu")) {
            setIsMenuClicked(false)
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', (e) => handleOnClick(e))
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', (e) => handleOnClick(e))
        };
    }, [])
```

Thx.